# Substring in Corpus in tm package

Tags: r, substring, tm

I have created a corpus using following command:

```
corpus_map <-VCorpus(VectorSource(classified_narr_sel$NARRATION))
corpus_map <- tm_map(corpus_map, removeNumbers)
```

The above command removes numbers from the corpus. Is there any command such that I can sub-string all the words of a corpus? eg: "Travelling" should be converted #to substring of 3 letters as "tra". Normally, I would use

```
substr("travelling",1,3)
```

but I want to do the same thing for the corpus in tm

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to do the conversions you want and run it on the corpus, so for example:

```
ConvertStrings <- function(textInput){
textOutput <- gsub("travelling", "tra", textInput)
textOutput <- gsub("furtherWords", "further", textOutput)
#...
return(textOutput)
}
corpus_transformed <- ConvertStrings(corpus_map)
```

Comment: But how can I do this for every word in each document, upto 3 characters? Here, travelling is being subbed as "tra". Will it apply for all the words?